# how to split a derivative of a function from R to R into derivatives of functions from R to R^d

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Assume the following:

> $(1)$ Let $f: R \to R$.
>
> $(2)$ Moreover, let $f = g \circ h$,
>
> $(3)$ where $h:R\to R^d$, and $g: R^d \to R$

then the derivative of $f$ can be written as:
$f' =h' \cdot g'\circ h$
i.e.:

> $(4)$ $f'(x)=h'(x) \cdot g'(h(x))$

However, since $h$ and $g$ are not straightforward functions from $R$ to $R$, I am not sure how to interpret this equation correctly.

So my questions:

1. Is equation $(4)$ correct, and is there a single correct way of interpreting it?
2. How should I interpret $(4)$ so that $h'(x)$ and $g'(h(x))$ can be explicitly calculated separately?

ps. I am aware of the existence of gradients and such in multivariate calculus, and have some experience with them, but apparently not enough to know what to do in this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\vec}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}$(4) is a special case of the **multivariate chain rule**, with $m=p=1,n=d$.

> Let $m,n,p \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\vec{f}:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m,\vec{g}:\mathbb{R}^p \to \mathbb{R}^n$. If $\vec{g}$ is differentiable at $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{f}$ is differentiable at $\vec{g}(\vec{x})$, then $\vec{f} \circ \vec{g}$ is differentiable at $\vec{x}$ with $$(\vec{f} \circ \vec{g})'(\vec{x}) = \vec{f}'(\vec{g}(\vec{x}))\vec{g}'(\vec{x})$$

Here $\vec{f}' \equiv \mathrm D\vec{f}$ is the local linear approximation of $\vec{f}$ by a linear map a.k.a. [Fréchet Derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_the_derivative#Multivariable_calculus). Notice that your formula for (4) is not right since $\vec h'$ is a column vector while $g'$ is a row vector. You can't put $\vec h'$ on the left as such multiplications do not make sense. Moreover you need the assumption that $\vec h',g'$ exists.

In your case, $\vec{h}'$ is the vector $\left[h_0',\dots,h_{d-1}'\right]^\intercal$ with elements being the derivative of the components of $\vec{h}$, and $g'$ is the derivative of $g$ given in a matrix. The transpose of this matrix is known as the gradient of $g$ and denoted $\nabla g$.